# ¿Cómo hago para visualizar Javascript en Chrome?

Tags: javascript, console

Estoy creando una página web y no puedo ver el código Javascript en Consol de Inspect. Me tira el siguiente **comentario** :

"Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform"

En español:

Una página o secuencia de comandos accede al menos a uno de navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion y navigator.platform. A partir de Chrome 101, se reducirá la cantidad de información disponible en la cadena del agente de usuario.
Para solucionar este problema, reemplace el uso de navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion y navigator.platform con detección de características, mejora progresiva o migre a navigator.userAgentData.
Tenga en cuenta que, por motivos de rendimiento, solo se muestra el primer acceso a una de las propiedades.

Quisiera saber como lo soluciono porque esta vez no entiendo nada jaja gracias!

[image: Muestro Console de Inspect para demostrar que el Javascript no aparece y como resultado me tira un comentario]

Comment: Hola amigo mira en Stack Overflow explican por que sale ese mensaje y dicen como evitarlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68982181/issue-audit-usage-of-navigator-useragent-navigator-appversion-and-navigator-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para poder ver como tal tu Js, en la herramienta para desarrolladores ve a **Sources**, en mi caso tengo un archivo index.html y un jsindex.js:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver se muestra el archivo .js y .html

Si lo que quieres es imprimir en consola lo que tiene tu variable o bloque de código, puedes hacerlo con un **console.log("text or var")** .

Saludos